# Comparing Dates in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to compare dates in a query given to SQLALchemy as follows:

```
start = time.strptime(start, "%d%m%y")
end = time.strptime(end, "%d%m%y")
list_ideas = Idea.query.filter(time >= start, time <= end).all()
```

However, this does not return results regardless of dates given (where `Idea.time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())`). I've searched through some other answers regarding this topic and from what I have gathered, I am not making the same mistakes.

In addition, changing the query to `Idea.query.filter(time >= start, time <= end, deleted=False).all()` gives the error:

> TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deleted'

Any pointers would be appreciated.

--
EDIT: I noticed that I was using `import time`, which may have caused the error. However, after changing it to `from time import strptime`, I now experience the error:

> NameError: global name 'time' is not defined

Comment: Try this? `Idea.query.filter(Idea.time >= start, Idea.time <= end).all()`

Comment: @AlexanderChen This gives the error "StatementError: SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input. (original cause: TypeError: SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.) u'SELECT idea.id AS idea_id, idea.user_id AS idea_user_id, idea.title AS idea_title, idea.edited AS idea_edited, idea.time AS idea_time, idea.post AS idea_post, idea.category AS idea_category, idea.deleted AS idea_deleted, idea.votes AS idea_votes \nFROM idea \nWHERE idea.time >= ? AND idea.time <= ?' [immutabledict({})]"

Comment: Okay, now try this: `from datetime import datetime` and `datetime.strptime(start, "%d%m%y")` for start and end (and also the above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime

Idea.query.filter(Idea.time >= datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                  Idea.time <= datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')).all()
```

you will just need to change the pattern to match what ever format you are using

Comment: Another possible way is just `Idea.time.date()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the func.DATE() function:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

start = time.strptime(start, "%d%m%y")
end = time.strptime(end, "%d%m%y")
list_ideas = Idea.query.filter(func.DATE(time) >= start, func.DATE(time) <= end).all()
```

refer to similar [issue](https://gist.github.com/danielthiel/8374607).